# Django for web-service for Android client

Tags: android, django, web-services

I creating a client on Android to interface with a web-service I would like to create using django.  I was was wondering if anyone knows of any good projects or examples to make this easier.  I recall a great django api module, but I have been unable to find it again (I will keep looking).  On the Android side, I could use any advice (json vs xml, ...etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar project and use [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) on the server side. You can export to many formats (XML, Json, etc) but I prefer Json.

On the client side I use [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) to create the interface in HTML5, so it is platform independent. We deploy on Android and iOS. Sencha also makes it very easy to consume Json and even store the data offline.

Comment: How well does Sencha Touch perform over mobile Internet?  From what I have seen, it has a lot of js files you need to transfer.

Comment: It's a little heavyweight.. Actually you only need 2 files, sencha-touch.js which is 337kb minified, and the stylesheet which is 150kb (minified!). You could serve it compressed via gzip and cache it in the browser, might take a while on first load. We package the application natively via PhoneGap, so everything is local and very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Django Piston works well for creating an API.  I used it to create an Android interface recently and it seemed to do the trick.  It supports exporting data in XML, YAML, JSON, etc, and you can create your own output formats.  You can get it to work with oauth and basic http authentication.

Anyway, might be worth a look.